How can we determine whether a SIM-Swap has occurred within a specific timeframe (hours/days/etc.) for a mobile user (MSISDN)?
In the context of SIM-Swap functionality, I'm seeking a method to extract the following details from DIAMETER messages interfacing with the HSS, or any network interface that offers such information:
How to ascertain whether a SIM-Swap has been executed within a specified time frame (hours/days/etc.) for a given mobile user (MSISDN).
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a reference from the 3GPP specification.
Thus far, I've referenced 3GPP spec 29.336, which only indicates whether a SIM-Swap has occurred for the specified mobile user (MSISDN), without specifying the time frame.
